# Turn list of key/value pairs into list of values per key in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, combiners

We need to efficiently convert large lists of key/value pairs, like this:

```
val providedData = List(
        (new Key("1"), new Val("one")),
        (new Key("1"), new Val("un")),
        (new Key("1"), new Val("ein")),
        (new Key("2"), new Val("two")),
        (new Key("2"), new Val("deux")),
        (new Key("2"), new Val("zwei"))
)
```

into lists of values per key, like this:

```
val expectedData = List(
  (new Key("1"), List(
    new Val("one"), 
    new Val("un"), 
    new Val("ein"))),
  (new Key("2"), List(
    new Val("two"), 
    new Val("deux"), 
    new Val("zwei")))
)
```

The key value pairs are from a large key/value store (Accumulo), so the keys will be sorted, but will usually cross spark partition boundaries. There can be millions of keys and hundreds of values per key.

I think the right tool for this job is spark's combineByKey operation, but have been only able to find terse examples with generic types (like Int), that I've been unable to generalize to user-defined types such as above.

Since I suspect many others will have the same question, I'm hoping someone can provide both fully-specified (verbose) and terse examples of the scala syntax for using combineByKey with user-defined types as above, or possibly point out a better tool that I've missed.

Comment: Sorry for the false  alarm. Its working fine as compiled code, just not in the REPL. I'm good now. Thanks!

Comment: This is an open issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2620

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really a Spark expert, but based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246756/how-createcombiner-mergevalue-mergecombiner-works-in-combinebykey-in-spark-us), I think you can do the following:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(providedData)

rdd.combineByKey(
    // createCombiner: add first value to a list
    (x: Val) => List(x),
    // mergeValue: add new value to existing list
    (acc: List[Val], x) => x :: acc,
    // mergeCominber: combine the 2 lists
    (acc1: List[Val], acc2: List[Val]) => acc1 ::: acc2
)
```

Using `aggregateByKey`:

```
rdd.aggregateByKey(List[Val]())(
    (acc, x) => x :: acc,
    (acc1, acc2) => acc1 ::: acc2
)
```

Comment: Hmmm; I'm geting this: scala> r.collect
res4: Array[(Key, List[Val])] = Array((1,List(ein)), (1,List(one)), (1,List(un)), (2,List(deux)), (2,List(two)), (2,List(zwei)))

Comment: @Bradjcox Have you implemented `Key` as a case class or a normal class? In the latter instance, you should override the `equals` method. Try `case class Key(key: String)`

Comment: Here is the Key class I'm using: @SerialVersionUID(123L)
case class Key(v: String) extends Serializable {
 val n = v;
  override def toString: String = { return n; }
  override def equals(o: Any) = o match {
    case that: Key => that.n.equals(this.n)
    case _ => false
  }
  override def hashCode = n.hashCode
}

Comment: Sorry for the false  alarm. Its working fine as compiled code, just not in the REPL. I'm good now. Thanks!

Comment: In this case, an `aggregateByKey` would work. No need to go with the more complex signature.

Comment: Hmmm, the new code doesn't compile in eclipse: type mismatch; found: List(Val) required Nil.type. And how would it acquire a List to extend? How is aggregateByKey better than combineByKey?

Comment: @Bradjcox I have updated my answer. `aggregateByKey` actually uses `combineByKey` [underneath](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala#L124-137).

Comment: Something's still wrong with the aggregateByKey example. But no biggie; I'm good with combineByKey<br>(1,one)
(2,deux)
(2,zwei)
(1,un)
(1,ein)
(2,two)